# Solution to Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function

Tags: php

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Patchwork\redefine()
```

I am sure that this is one of the most common question in StackOverflow and the below solutions are found in several posts here in SO.

```
if (!function_exists('view')) {
   function view()
   {
      //your code here
   }
}
```

or you can use

```
include_once() or require_once()
```

**My Problem:**
I am developing a plugin for a CMS which uses a 3rd party library. The CMS has another plugin developed by another developer using the same library that I use.

Due to 2 declaration of same classes/functions, I am getting the fatal error.

Editing the 3rd party library to use the function_exists check for all functions is not a friendly approach in my opinion.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Well you could put your function called `redefine()` in a different namespace although wheter that makes logical sense is difficult to tell from the information in your question

Comment: I have thought about the same. Changes related to namespace would be lost when the libraries are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the owner of the Patchwork library has made updates to his library to avoid these issues.

So for now the issue stands closed.